# Setting default value in Oracle Object Type Constructor Function

Tags: oracle, function, types, plsql, object-type

I want to set default values in Oracle object type, but it requires all attributes needs to be passed in constructor function for that.

Is there anyway, so that I can pass only required attributes in constructor function for which default value is required.

Please see the following details

```
    SQL> CREATE TYPE TYPE_SUB AS OBJECT(
      2  COL1 NUMBER,
      3  COL2 VARCHAR2(100)
      4  )
      5  NOT FINAL
      6  /

    Type created.

    SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_MAIN
      2  UNDER TYPE_SUB
      3  (
      4  COL3 varchar2(10),
      5  COL4 VARCHAR2(10),
      6  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TYPE_MAIN(COL1 NUMBER, COL2 VARCHAR2, COL3 varchar2, COL4 VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT)
      7  NOT FINAL
      8  /

    Type created.

    SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TYPE_MAIN  IS
      2  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TYPE_MAIN (COL1 NUMBER, COL2 VARCHAR2, COL3 varchar2, COL4 VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
      3  BEGIN
      4   SELF.COL1 := nvl(COL1,123);
      5   SELF.COL2 := nvl(COL2,'NA');
      6   SELF.COL3 := nvl(COL3,'NA');
      7   SELF.COL4 := nvl(COL4,NULL);
      8   RETURN;
      9  end;
     10  END;
     11  /

    Type body created.

    SQL> CREATE TABLE TAB_MAIN  (
      2  PKEY NUMBER,
      3  COLTEST VARCHAR2(100),
      4  COLNEW TYPE_MAIN)
      5  /

    Table created.

    SQL> INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY) VALUES(1)
      2  /

    1 row created.

    SQL> INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY,COLTEST,COLNEW) VALUES(1,'TESTCOL',TYPE_MAIN('1','2',NULL,NULL))
      2  /

    1 row created.

    SQL> INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY,COLTEST,COLNEW) VALUES(1,'TESTCOL2',TYPE_MAIN('1',NULL,NULL,NULL))
      2  /

    1 row created.

    SQL> SELECT * FROM TAB_MAIN
      2  /

          PKEY COLTEST    COLNEW(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
    ---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
             1
             1 TESTCOL    TYPE_MAIN(1, '2', 'NA', NULL)
             1 TESTCOL2   TYPE_MAIN(1, 'NA', 'NA', NULL)
```

Now, in above example if I will pass only Col3 and Col4 attribute in constructor function for default value, then it didn't work.  Please see the following example.

```
    SQL> CREATE TYPE TYPE_SUB AS OBJECT(
      2  COL1 NUMBER,
      3  COL2 VARCHAR2(100)
      4  )
      5  NOT FINAL
      6  /

    Type created.

    SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_MAIN
      2  UNDER TYPE_SUB
      3  (
      4  COL3 varchar2(10),
      5  COL4 VARCHAR2(10),
      6  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TYPE_MAIN(COL3 varchar2, COL4 VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT)
      7  NOT FINAL
      8  /

    Type created.

    SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TYPE_MAIN  IS
      2  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TYPE_MAIN (COL3 varchar2, COL4 VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
      3  BEGIN
      4   SELF.COL3 := nvl(COL3,'NA');
      5   SELF.COL4 := nvl(COL4,NULL);
      6   RETURN;
      7  end;
      8  END;
      9  /

    Type body created.

    SQL> CREATE TABLE TAB_MAIN  (
      2  PKEY NUMBER,
      3  COLTEST VARCHAR2(100),
      4  COLNEW TYPE_MAIN)
      5  /

    Table created.

    SQL> INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY) VALUES(1)
      2  /

    1 row created.

    SQL> INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY,COLTEST,COLNEW) VALUES(1,'TESTCOL',TYPE_MAIN('1','2',NULL,NULL))
      2  /

    1 row created.

    SQL> INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY,COLTEST,COLNEW) VALUES(1,'TESTCOL2',TYPE_MAIN('1',NULL,NULL,NULL))
      2  /

    1 row created.

    SQL> SELECT * FROM TAB_MAIN
      2  /

          PKEY COLTEST    COLNEW(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
    ---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
             1
             1 TESTCOL    TYPE_MAIN(1, '2', NULL, NULL)
             1 TESTCOL2   TYPE_MAIN(1, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Answer (score 5):

In your second code block, you aren't calling the constructor that only has two arguments. Passing a null argument doesn't mean you use the other constructor, you're calling the (default) constructor with four arguments, two of which just happen to be intentionally null. You're effectively doing:

```
TYPE_MAIN(col1 => '1', col2 => NULL, col3 => NULL, col4 => NULL)
```

not

```
TYPE_MAIN(col3 => '1', col4 => NULL)
```

So this works:

```
INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY,COLTEST,COLNEW) VALUES(1,'TESTCOL2',TYPE_MAIN('3','4'))
/

...

      PKEY COLTEST         COLNEW                                           
---------- --------------- --------------------------------------------------
         1                                                                    
         1 TESTCOL         TYPE_MAIN(1,'2',NULL,NULL)           
         1 TESTCOL2        TYPE_MAIN(1,NULL,NULL,NULL)          
         1 TESTCOL2        TYPE_MAIN(NULL,NULL,'3','4')
```

To get the defaults to work as I think you intend in your first code block, set them in the constructor parameters, not in the body of the constructor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_MAIN
UNDER TYPE_SUB
(
COL3 varchar2(10),
COL4 VARCHAR2(10),
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TYPE_MAIN(COL1 number default 123,
  COL2 VARCHAR2 default 'NA',
  COL3 varchar2 default 'NA',
  COL4 VARCHAR2 default null) RETURN SELF AS RESULT)
NOT FINAL
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TYPE_MAIN  IS
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TYPE_MAIN (COL1 number default 123,
  COL2 VARCHAR2 default 'NA',
  COL3 varchar2 default 'NA',
  COL4 VARCHAR2 default null) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
BEGIN
 SELF.COL1 := COL1;
 SELF.COL2 := COL2;
 SELF.COL3 := COL3;
 SELF.COL4 := COL4;
RETURN;
end;
END;
/
```

Then when only passing one of the arguments (or any time you aren't passing them all, or the first few that you want to override in order starting from `col1`) you need to name it, rather than passing `null` for the others, as that would only override the defaults.

```
INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY) VALUES(1)
/

INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY,COLTEST,COLNEW)
VALUES(1,'TESTCOL',TYPE_MAIN(1,'2'))
/

INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY,COLTEST,COLNEW)
VALUES(1,'TESTCOL2',TYPE_MAIN(1))
/

INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY,COLTEST,COLNEW)
VALUES(1,'TESTCOL3',TYPE_MAIN(col3 => '3'))
/

INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY,COLTEST,COLNEW)
VALUES(1,'TESTCOL4',TYPE_MAIN(col4 => '4'))
/

      PKEY COLTEST         COLNEW                                           
---------- --------------- --------------------------------------------------
         1                                                                    
         1 TESTCOL         TYPE_MAIN(1,'2','NA',NULL)           
         1 TESTCOL2        TYPE_MAIN(1,'NA','NA',NULL)          
         1 TESTCOL3        TYPE_MAIN(123,'NA','3',NULL)         
         1 TESTCOL4        TYPE_MAIN(123,'NA','NA','4')
```

To pass both `col3` and `col4` you'll still need to name the arguments, otherwise it will assume you're starting from `col1`:

```
INSERT INTO TAB_MAIN(PKEY,COLTEST,COLNEW)
VALUES(1,'TESTCOL5',TYPE_MAIN(col3 => '3', col4 => '4'))
/

      PKEY COLTEST         COLNEW                                           
---------- --------------- --------------------------------------------------
         1                                                                    
         1 TESTCOL         TYPE_MAIN(1,'2','NA',NULL)           
         1 TESTCOL2        TYPE_MAIN(1,'NA','NA',NULL)          
         1 TESTCOL3        TYPE_MAIN(123,'NA','3',NULL)         
         1 TESTCOL4        TYPE_MAIN(123,'NA','NA','4')         
         1 TESTCOL5        TYPE_MAIN(123,'NA','3','4')
```